# How do I convert a Cordova app from Angular Dart 1 to Angular 2?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I'm upgrading a cordova Angular Dart 1 app to Angular 2.

In angular Dart 1 ,  I was able to make it work by overwriting ResourceUrlResolver class using a wrapper class like specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704577/angular-dart-relative-url-resolution-requires-a-valid-base-uri)

How can I do the same with angular 2

Comment: I've added [crosswalk plugin](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) and everything is ok now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be necessary in Angular 2 Dart as templates and CSS are precompiled as part of `pub build`. Therefore, there's no more `ResourceUrlResolver`.